# Sending extra GET data to the login_check on Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Im using the normal user authentication system proposed on the symfony documentation:

```
    form_login:
        login_path: /login
        check_path: /login_check
```

As you know you write the controller for `/login` and then send the form data to `/login_check` that is handle by the framework. Sometimes my users comes with a sort of gift code so the write `/login?code=12345678`, given the fact that I wrote the login controller i can parse this code, but one i send the login data to `/login_check` I lost control of this code because as i said the script behind `/login_check` is not writen by me. I need to send the code because if the login is complete ideally i take the get data and store it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a new Bundle, extending SecurityBundle and then you just need to override login_check action... Official documentation is [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) It seems a bit heavy for a gift code.

Why don't you store the gift code in session (if it exists) ? Anyway, if login fails, the user can't access to the site part it may be used. And why not to wait it's been used to invalidate it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not good. Read this to understand how it's work: http://blog.logicexception.com/2011/10/symfony2-securitybundle-and.html

You need to create your own user provider.